# Incomplete setter for set field+mappedBy

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

Scenario:

```
entity --class ~.domain.Team
entity --class Person
field reference --fieldName team --type Team
focus --class Team
field set --fieldName members --type Person --mappedBy team
controller all --package ~.web
```

This generates standard CRUD scaffolding for People and Teams. When creating/updating a Team, there is a list selector for members, but changes are not persisted.

A workaround for this is to change setMembers in Team_Roo_JavaBean.aj:

```
public void Team.setMembers(Set<Person> members) {
    this.members = members;
    for (Person person : members) {
        person.setTeam(this);
    }
}
```

(added loop to update all referenced People, need to update those dereferenced as well...)

Why are changes to this [boilerplate] code necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a known blocker Spring Roo bug: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2365.